# Java 8 refactor switch statement that does different things for each case

Tags: java, java-8, switch-statement, refactoring

I have a switch statement that steps through a json file and does different things depending on the attribute in the file. For instance:

```
dataMap.forEach((k, v) -> {
        Product product = new Product();
        ProductLine productLine = new ProductLine();
        Vendor currentVendor = new Vendor();

        // Step over each atttribute in the line of the file
        v.forEach((k2, v2) -> {
            switch(k2) {
                case "Product Class": {
                    Set<ProductCategory> categories = new HashSet<>();
                    try {
                        List<String> categoryList = Arrays.asList(v2.split(","));
                        categoryList.forEach(it ->{
                            ProductCategory category = ProductCategory.loadTypeByValue(it.trim());
                            categories.add(category);
                        });                     
                        product.setProductCategories(categories);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        //
                    }
                    break;
                }                
                case "Product Name": {
                    product.setName(v2);
                    productLine.setName(v2);
                    break;
                }
                case "SKU": {
                    product.setSKU(v2);
                    break;
                }
                case "Name": {
                    vendor.setName(v2);
                }
           ....
```

Since these case statements work with different objects (`Product`, `ProductLine`, and `Vendor`), and each case sometimes requires a `Producer`, `Consumer`, or `Function` interface, how can I refactor the whole switch (preferably using Lambdas of some sort)? I thought of using a Map, with the key being the case, like "Product Class", but what would be the value?

```
Map <String, ?> = new HashMap<>();
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can't you create a class that reflects the json structure and just parse the input?

Answer (score -1):

It's just idea but why not just do something like this:

```
dataMap.forEach((k, v) -> {
        Product product = new Product();
        ProductLine productLine = new ProductLine();
        Vendor currentVendor = new Vendor();

    List<Entry<K,V>> vSet = v.entrySet();
    vSet.stream().filter((v)->"Product Class".equals(v.getKey()))
             .foreach((v)->addCategoriesToProduct(product, v.getKey(), v.getValue()));


    vSet.stream().filter(((v)->"Product Name".equals(v.getKey()))
             .foreach((v)->fillProductName(product, v.getValue()));


    vSet.stream().filter((v)->"SKU".equals(v.getKey()))
             .foreach((v)->fillProductName(product, v.getValue()));
```

Edit: Maybe he want's somethink like this;

```
r = new ProductAttributeResolver( v.entrySet());

product.setCategories(r.getAllCategories());
product.setName(r.getProductName());
...
```

then getProductName will looks like:

```
   return vSet.stream().filter(((v)->"Product Name".equals(v.getKey()))
             .map((v)->v.getValue())
             .findFirst()
             .orElse(null)
```

Comment: That looks pretty cool, but my lead doesn't like forEach statements. He told me to use a creator/resolver pattern, and I have no idea what that is!

Comment: Liking or not has no impact on how code works, tell him to get a grip on reality. ;)

Comment: Didn't you just **triple** the number of iterations?

Comment: @GhostCat  = filter is the key. :D

Comment: I see that you are filtering. But that still means that you are *tripling* the overall number of iterations. You still have to *check* each element in the stream and apply the filter to it.

Comment: Yes but 'its light operation because what I do is just comparing strings.  And I would go with readability.

Comment: That depends on context. If you have to process millions of entries, you would probably change your mind.

Comment: @GhostCat if you had a milion entries to process, You wouldn't put them in json(if You are sane)

Answer (score -1):

Well, I think I've answered my own question. I defined each case as a `BiConsumer<String, Object>()`, and I'm setting up a `Map` for each attribute and its BiConsumer like so:

```
final static Map<String, BiConsumer<String, Object>> attributeMap = new HashMap<>();

private BiConsumer<String, Object> setVendorName = new BiConsumer<String, Object>() { 
    @Override
    public void accept(String value, Object obj) {
        ((Vendor)obj).setName(value);
    }
};

attributeMap.put("Vendor Name", setVendorName);
```

Comment: You don’t have to use BiConsumer.  You can write your own interface, with a method that accepts a value, a Product, and a Vendor.

Comment: Thanks. I don't always need both all three parameters though. So I just added an if-statement in the for-each.

Comment: Do not use object. Think about others using your code.